# Is there a better way than this to control dialog?

Tags: flutter

I am using dialog when screen loads. The problem is that if user closes the dialog and after that the pop function for dialog is triggered, then it will pop the page instead of dialog. (Navigator.pop(context). So I came up with a solution to use global key for dialog. Now the function detects if global key is mounted then it pops else not. I want to know if there is any better and shorter method.

I am using Navigator.pop(context) for dialog to pop. But if user closes the dialog box before closing itself, then it pops the page instead of dialog box.

```
  void loadingDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
          child: AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            key: dashboardLoadingDialogKey,
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF15000D),
            content: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  const CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text(
                    'LOADING',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: dialogAmber,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

T

```
    if (response.statusCode == 200 && mounted) {
        // dashboard loading dialog pop
        if (dashboardLoadingDialogKey.currentContext != null &&
            dashboardLoadingDialogKey.currentContext!.mounted) {
          Navigator.of(dashboardLoadingDialogKey.currentContext!).pop();
        }
      }
```

This is the function for dialog and I am using global key, and this is how  I am popping it

Comment: So, you want to show the dialog for the loading indication, but the problem is it gets dismissed, but Navigator will pop the current page in the dialog has been manually dismissed, correct?
If that's the case, the question would be: how the user is allowed to dismiss the dialog?!

Answer (score 1):

Loading dialog shouldn't be closed/popped by the user. So, I would wrap my `builder` widget with `WillPopScope` as the following so that it can be popped only programmatically:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: AlertDialog(
        // ...
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you do not do this via the `Navigator`, but simply use the `Overlay` or a `Stack` and simply use a `bool` there to indicate whether the overlay should be displayed.
This approach is also more compatible with most state management systems than manually pushing and popping dialogs. For the user, it would look identical if it was designed accordingly.

Comment: Can you please provide a basic example using overlay?

Comment: I just had a quick look on pub.dev and saw that there is already a package that provides an overlay for this. But I assume that you still have to add a `WillPopScope` and you also have to manually enable/disable loading here:
https://pub.dev/packages/loader_overlay

Answer (score 0):

It will pop all other route except base first route. It will help a lot when if you are using show dialog. If you used `Navigator.pop(context)`, sometimes all route will be pop because of user interaction.

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);
```